# Check http status code using symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comparison, httpclient, symbols, http-status-codes

I am using `HttpClient` and check status of its response:

```
http = HttpClient.new
res = http.post(................)
if res.status == 401
  ...............
end
```

I would like to use [symbols](http://futureshock-ed.com/2011/03/04/http-status-code-symbols-for-rails/) rather than codes:

```
if res.status == :unauthorized
  ...............
end
```

but this expression evaluates always as false.

How to compare status code with corresponding symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `workaround` for it, try creating an `array` like

```
array(100=>':continue',200=>':ok')
```

`compare` with the `keys` , and `show` them corresponding `array value` wherever needed.

Comment: @Paul yeah its workaround ,but it will possibly solve your requirements.

Comment: I possibly found a solution in gem sources: `if res.status == HTTP::Status::UNAUTHORIZED` but still hoping to use the symbols.